# How to select ListView Item in Java code?

Tags: android, listview, select

I have a Android ListView that has 5 Items. General speaking, if the ListView Item was selected by keyboard(the key is UP and Down etc), it will change its background and text color. Now I want to select the 3th Item ***in java code*** and hope it also change its background and text color like I use the keyboard to select it. How can I achieve that? By the way, there is one was selected at the same time and those wasn’t selected was black as usual. I will appreciated if someone can give me advice , Thanks !

Comment: The persistent highlight you see associated with keyboard focus is not applicable when in touch mode. Touch mode is toggled on when the user interacts with the touchscreen and toggled off when the user interacts with trackball or d-pad selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can:

```
ListView myList=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

myList.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
myList.setSelection(1);
```

where 1 represents the SECOND item in the list (its the position, starting at zero)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. Any other suggestions on how to (auto)select and highlight a given ListView item? I'm using API-18.

Comment: Found a working solution with: myList.performItemClick(myList, 1, -1)